# OpenCV find position of points in image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, points

I havent found a good answer for this problem yet. Im trying to find the position of a few points in a [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7kSx.png). Most answers use a simple threshold. Although this is creating problems for me as contrast between the points and background changes making the threshold value be different. Otsu solves this but sometimes the threshold is too low making noise a big problem.
Im trying to use adaptiveThresholding and that [gives me this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzfet.png)

It seems to work reliably, only problem is i need to now find the position of these points. FindContours gives me multiple contours per point for some reason.
Is there an algorithm that can maybe simply label the regions in the binary image?
Code:

```
vector<Point2f> pointsImage;

Mat gray;
cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

Mat blur;
GaussianBlur(gray, blur, cv::Size(5, 5), 0);

Mat bw;
cv::adaptiveThreshold(blur, bw, 255, cv::AdaptiveThresholdTypes::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 7, 5);

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(bw, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {

    if (isContourConvex(contours[i])) {

        Moments M = moments(contours[i]);
        Point2f c(M.m10/M.m00, M.m01/M.m00);

        if (!isnan(c.x) && !isnan(c.y) && !isinf(c.x) && !isinf(c.y)) pointsImage.push_back(c);

    }

}
```

Comment: show your inputs. please review [mre] and [ask].

Comment: @ChrisSteffen Within `adaptiveThreshold` function use the flag `THRESH_BINARY_INV`. This will preserve the boundary in white making it easy to find contours.

Comment: why do you even use adaptive thresholding? these points can be thresholded trivially. no adaptive anything required. it actually hurts you to use that. -- inverting the adaptive threshold won't do anything either, apart from inverting the whole thing, which leads to no improvement of the situation that I can see. -- this whole approach is overcomplicated. just use a SimpleBlobDetector

Comment: Gave the SimpleBlobDetector a try. It works but is too slow. One frame (1080p) takes roughly 20ms on my computer and it need to run on a raspberry pi zero.

Comment: ok then, plain `threshold()` and connectedComponentsWithStats/findContours. if those don't run fast enough, nothing will.